# How to run multiple commands within a single task in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to make a custom configuration step for a custom build system. It looks like:

```
binary1 arg1 arg2 …
binary2 arg3 arg4 …
<internal vscode command from other extension>
```

I want to bind this to a single shortcut, and the tasks mechanism looks like a suitable solution. But I can't figure out how to express my intention in a proper task json format.

How to do that?

Or maybe there is a better approach to my problem than using tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode features [Compound Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks).

You define the steps of your build process as separate tasks and then reference them from the compound task.

Comment: A worked out example that is easy to follow, unlike anything in the VSCode online docs, would have been helpful.